# Using sphinxsearch or lucene for SQL Server and .net

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, search-engine

I have a complex crm db schema and I need to support google-style type-ahead searching that will search a number of different columns from a number of different tables with joins involved etc. I was therefore considering building some sort of cached text search facility.  I noticed sphinxsearch and lucene and wondered if anyone had any words of wisdom on using these in a .NET context, or whether there are any other open source offerings or alternative design patterns that people might recommend. I have tried MS Full Text and been disappointed by it so I'm looking for alternatives. Thanks very much.

Comment: Have a look at lucene as well. I believe it even has a .NET port : http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Comment: @JohnP - thanks John, looks interesting, I have edited the question to include the lucene reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, Lucene looks very good in testing - we'll probably use it.

Answer (score 0):

For type-ahead search you should check out some of Chen Li's papers. I'm not sure how much your system needs to scale, but if it's beyond a few concurrent users then you'll need to dive deeper than out of the box lucene, solr, or sphinx. It's been a while since I read his papers, and he has some new ones, but the ones I remember all used tries. You're likely better off using n-grams than tries. I hope that makes some sense :)

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~chenli/pubs.html